# How do I define a constructor outside of a template class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a class template with one constructor inside that is not yet defined.

My goal is to define this constructor outside of the class template.

Is this possible? How can I do this? I have checked my C++ book and searched the web, but I cannot seem to find an answer. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T> class Calculate {

public:
    Calculate ();

};

int main() {

    return 0;

}

// I want to define this constructor right here
template <class T> <int> Calculate () {
    std::cout << "Constructor";
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile this code? How do you know it doesn't already work?

Comment: Hi, this code gives me an error. I was wondering if someone had a workaround for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax would be

```
template <class T>
Calculate<T>::Calculate()
{
    std::cout << "Constructor";
}
```

Comment: What if I had 2 items in my template? Like <class T, class U> How would I go about this?

Comment: `template <class T, class U> Foo<T, U>::Foo() { /*..*/}`